# Is it safe to set WinSCP INI file read only to avoid problems during parallel script runs?

Tags: scripting, file-access, winscp

We have multiple WinSCP processes to upload/download files from external servers. These jobs run to a schedule but can often overlap as they are running so frequently.

There are occasions where we can successfully upload a file to a server, however WinSCP exits as if it has failed, because it cannot write back to the **ini** file.

```
Error writting to file 'c:\progra~1\winSCP\WinSCP.ini'
System Error.  Code: 32.

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

It appears that this is due to two or more processes trying to write back to the ini file at the same time.

This is then causing us to treat the files uploaded as failures and re-upload them on the next run (not great when you're dealing with transactional data)

According to the [Configuration Guide](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/config#ini), we can set the properties of the WinSCP ini file to read-only:

> Particularly when using shared INI file, you can set read-only
>   attribute to the INI file to prevent WinSCP from overwriting the file.

Before making this change, I was hoping someone could tell me the following:

What exactly gets written back to the file?
What issues could arise from setting the file to **Read-Only**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, no important data are written after script run, maybe some caches, statistics, etc. You can compare the INI file before and after the run to see yourself.

You can probably turn off all these to avoid WinSCP from writing them, but [setting the INI file read only](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/config#ini_readonly) is more reliable and I would recommend it anyway. You would have **no problems** with that.

Though the best practice is [not to rely on external configuration](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#configuration).

Comment: Great, we'll give that a whirl